# Google map: Errors showing following tutorials to store geocode results and call them back to create a map

Tags: php, javascript, xml, google-maps, geocode

I'm following two tutorials from Google:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html#createmap

I have the first tutorial working correctly, it's geocoding several database addresses and saving the lat/lng results.

I'm having a bit of trouble with the second tutorial, calling the results and creating a map. Firstly, are these the correct tutorials to follow to geocode thousands of addresses and create a map?

I've followed the tutorial down to the bottom of the page but have a few errors, the first being this:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/medicom/public_html/mapping/wp-content/themes/default/header.php:8)
>   in
>   /home/medicom/public_html/mapping/wp-content/themes/default/header.php
>   on line 134

Line 134 being this:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

How can I correct this? The page I'm working on is this http://www.mediwales.com/mapping

Update:

This seems to be the problomatic bit of code:

```
<?php
require("phpsqlgeocode_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM _health WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Is there an alternative to the `header()` above?

Comment: 5,000+ duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent+by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into, and fixed this problem!

The php file in the tutorial that renders the xml file (http://bit.ly/uVTqoh) has to be it's own.

There shouldn't be anything else other than that snippet from the tutorial; don't try and slot that in alongside any html. `header` sends a raw http header to the client, and if something's already been defined, then you can see the confuzzlement the browser must feel.

Then, when you reference the .php file in the `GDownloadURL` function, it pulls the info from the xml that that script outputs. Dig?

Answer (score 0):

`header()` function should be called before any content will printed out.

So, check that you don't `echo`ing anything before calling `header`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the code everywhere and removed all the whitespace yet it's still coming up. I'm using Wordpress so think that's causing an issue.